# Gear Ratio And Torque Relationship

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, torque, power

suppose a gear teeth ratio of (1:10) >> then it is obvious that the smaller gear will be faster than the larger gear >> And the higher gear has more torque which means a higher acceleration >> Now to keep the ratio (1:10) constant >> the smaller gear has to accelerate faster than the larger gear >> If so, why are reduction gears used to provide more acceleration why not the inverse since the smaller gears should accelerate faster to maintain the (1:10) ratio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angular acceleration of the smaller one must be 10 times its coupling pair. It is what happens when a car moves from the rest. The motor's RPM grows faster than the wheels' RPM. On the other hand, the available torque for the wheels is greater than that on the motor axis.

It is only in the case that the second gear is free to spin, (without all the mass of the car as a load for example), the torque on its axis is proportional to its acceleration, and depends on its own moment of inertia:
$$\tau_2 = I_2\alpha_2 = \frac{1}{10}I_2\alpha_1$$

Comment: You literally answered my question thank you a lot .